# How to reorder multiple elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice, array-splice, reorderlist

I have an array `arr`:

`arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5]`

How can I reorder/ shift multiple elements? For example,

- I want to remove `0,2 and 3` and put them at index 4 so that the final array should be `[1,0,2,3,4,5]`

In the above example, index 4 is with the perspective of the original array, not the final array.

I tried using splice like this:

```
items = [0,2,3] // items to be reordered
indexes = [0,2,3] // get their indexes
arr = [...arr.filter((it)=> !indexes.includes(arr.indexOf(it)))]
arr.splice(4, 0, ...items)
// result [1, 4, 5, 0, 2, 3]
```

The above is not the intended result

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: how can the index of original array , where `3` is on index `3` later yield the values after `4` ?

Comment: I corrected the mistake and updated the question

Comment: You've edited the question so that your required output has the spliced data at index 1 now.

Comment: yes, the final output has the sliced data at index 1. The information we know before solving the problem is the index according to the original array. i.e. we want to place [0,2,3] at index 4 of the original array - we don't care about the index of final output

Answer (score 2):

This solution mutates the array.

You could store the value at the inser position and remove the items and splice the removed items after the index of the stored item.

> ```
> position             v
> index    0  1  2  3  4
> array   [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]              store value at index
>             1        4  5               rest array after removing items
>             1        4 [0  2  3] 5      splice with removed items
> ```

```js
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    remove = [0, 2, 3],
    insertAtIndex = 4,
    valueAtPosition = array[insertAtIndex];
    
remove.forEach(v => array.splice(array.indexOf(v), 1));
array.splice(array.indexOf(valueAtPosition) + 1, 0, ...remove);

console.log(...array);
```

Comment: I have already updated the question. Can you go through it again?

Answer (score 1):

You can first remove the given elements and then use `splice()` to add them at the required index.

```js
function shiftElementsTo(arr, inds, final){
   let set = new Set(inds);
   let removed = inds.map(x => arr[x]);
   arr = arr.filter((x, i) => !set.has(i));
   arr.splice(final, 0, ...removed);
   return arr;
}

console.log(shiftElementsTo([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 2, 3], 2))
```

Comment: the final index should be 3 not 2

Comment: That makes no sense. In your question the extracted data is at index 2 of your required output. @HarisMuzaffar.

Comment: sorry updating the comment: the index where items are to be placed is 4, not 3. And extracted data is at index 2 but ```2``` is not known before. It is the index ```4``` which is known and this index 4 is with the perspective of the original array.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const temp = [0, 2, 3];
const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const index = arr[4];

// Accepts an array (temp) and returns a function to be used
// as the callback for `filter` which accepts an element
// and returns whether that element is in the temp array
const filterUsing = (arr) => (el) => !arr.includes(el);

// `filter` the elements from the main array
const filtered = arr.filter(filterUsing(temp));

// Find the new position of the element in `index`
const newIndex = filtered.findIndex(el => el === index);

// Splice in the temp array back into the filtered array
filtered.splice(newIndex, 0, ...temp);

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this approach:

```js
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
let rmv = [0, 2, 3];

const remove = (src, rem, i ) => {
  const arrWithIndexes = src.map((a, i) => { return  {value: a, index: i}});
  const filtered = arrWithIndexes.filter(f => !rem.some(s=> s === f.value));
  const indexToInsert = filtered.findIndex(f=>f.index === i);
  const result = filtered.map(f=> f.value);
  result.splice(indexToInsert, 0, ...rem);
  console.log(result);
}

console.log(remove(arr, rmv, 4));
```

Or if you know the desired index:

```js
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
let rmv = [0, 2, 3];

const remove = (src, rem ) => {
  const filtered = src.filter(f=> !rem.some(s=> s === f));
  filtered.splice(2, 0, ...rmv)
  console.log(filtered);

}

console.log(remove(arr, rmv));
```

Comment: Where are you using the index where [0,2,3] are to be added?